# How to specify margins for Barrier in Constraintlayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am unsure about the best way to specify margins in ConstraintLayout around a Barrier.

I tried setting them in the barrier element, but this has no effect and I also couldn't find any documentation on that.

```
   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
            android:id="@+id/detail_barrier"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:barrierDirection="top"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:constraint_referenced_ids="detail_header_1,detail_header_2" />
```

Comment: Add the margin for the element against the barrier, the elements that are gonna be pushed by the barrier

Comment: Thanks @cutiko , I already tried that, the problem is that then I need to add the margin to all the elements, I wanted to avoid this redundancy by using a barrier

Comment: That is how constraint layout margins work, you can't push away one element with others, but the element setting the constraint to another can distance itself from that

Comment: @Displayname If you only need the margin with the `Barrier` so that you can set same margin for all constrained elements, would using `GuideLine` make more sense? This way you could set `app:layout_constraintGuide_end` and `app:layout_constraintGuide_start`.

Comment: @theThapa I used the Barrier because it depends on specific views and not just on a margin from the edges, because as far as I understood Guidelines can't be dependant on specific views

Comment: @Displayname Can you please post full xml view to help picture what you are intending to do?

Answer (score 36):

Using what azEf recommended works, but you need 2 views instead of 1, and also the barrier will look off at the Layout Preview. The built-in way to do this is `app:barrierMargin`. Example:

[image: preview of the barrier + barrierMargin usage]

```xml
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_available"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/panelStart" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/iconEnd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierMargin="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:barrierDirection="end"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="icon" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/title_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/iconEnd"
        tools:text="Title" />
```

Comment: There's no such thing as app:barrierMargin=""

Comment: It does indeed exist. It's declared as `<attr format="dimension" name="barrierMargin"/>`. It could be that this was introduced with ConstraintLayout 2.0, and you are still using 1.x?

Comment: this will add margin for both sides: top/bottom or start/end

Comment: Works great! But `android:orientation="vertical"` is redundant

Comment: In my case margin in negative worked `app:barrierMargin="@dimen/_minus12sdp"`

Answer (score 3):

You could constrain a `Space` view to the barrier and add the margin on it.

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
            android:id="@+id/detail_barrier"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:barrierDirection="top"
            app:constraint_referenced_ids="detail_header_1,detail_header_2" />

<Space
            android:id="@+id/detail_space"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/details_barrier" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This maybe coming late but for any that would come across same problem in the future, you can simply give a height or width instead of wrap_content to your Spacer and that solves the marginTop or marginBottom, marginStart or marginEnd issue as the case maybe be.

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_more"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/ripple"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/image_content"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_more_vert_24"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/tv_header"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tv_header" />

        <Space
            android:id="@+id/spacer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_8sdp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btn_more"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/v_menu"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/v_menu2"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/spacer" />
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use a View constraint with the Barrier with width or height set as 0dp, that way it won't be seen in the UI just like the Bar, but help provide constraint to other views.